# How to make a query like this?

Tags: google-bigquery

Sorry for the title since it´s not very explicit but i don´t know how to explain it correctly.

I´m tracking an event after succesfully completing a level in my game. I track the level number (NumNivel) and the attempts (NumIntentos)

[image: The data is saved with this structure:]

The question is i want to have an output data like this:

**Level Number / 1 Attempt / 2 Attempts / ... / 10 or more attempts**

I ran a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  Level AS Level_Number,
  MAX((value=1) * Levels) AS i1,
  MAX((value=2) * Levels) AS i2,
  MAX((value=3) * Levels) AS i3,
  MAX((value=4) * Levels) AS i4,
  MAX((value=5) * Levels) AS i5,
  MAX((value=6) * Levels) AS i6,
  MAX((value=7) * Levels) AS i7,
  MAX((value=8) * Levels) AS i8,
  MAX((value=9) * Levels) AS i9,
  MAX((value=10) * Levels) AS i10,

FROM (
    SELECT
      COUNT(event_name) AS Levels,
      event_params.key AS Level,
      event_params.value.int_value AS value
    FROM
      [tal:analytics_151354869.events_20180726]
    WHERE
      event_name = 'LevelComplete'
      AND event_params.key = 'NumNivel'
      AND app_info.id = 'com.game'
    GROUP BY Level, value
    )
GROUP BY Level_number
```

But what i have is a level count by number of level.

Is possible to do what i want?

Comment: please clarify the logic you have in mind, also provide example of data you have and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is not making it easy on you.  Since the values you are looking for are both stored in the same unstructured array, you have to Flatten and Join back to the array twice to get both pieces of information.

I think you want something like the below query (remove the 'source_table' bit and replace with your table).  This query joins with the event_params array once and picks out the LevelNumber (NumNivel) and joins a second time to pick out the NumAttempts (NumIntentos) in the same row.

```
WITH source_table AS (
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<event_name STRING, event_params ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<int_value INT64>>> >>
     [('LevelComplete', [('NumNivel', STRUCT(1)), ('NumIntentos', STRUCT(3))]),
      ('LevelComplete', [('NumNivel', STRUCT(2)), ('NumIntentos', STRUCT(5))])])
)
SELECT a.value.int_value AS LevelNumber, b.value.int_value AS NumAttempts
FROM source_table, UNNEST(event_params) a, UNNEST(event_params) b
WHERE event_name = 'LevelComplete'
AND a.key = 'NumNivel' AND b.key = 'NumIntentos'
;
```

References:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying-struct-elements-in-an-array